# How to write to Control Endpoint with PyUSB

Tags: python, endpoint, pyusb

I have a USB device for which the following code

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xC251, idProduct=0x2201)
print(device)
```

produces

```
DEVICE ID c251:2201 on Bus 002 Address 020 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0xc251
 idProduct              : 0x2201
 bcdDevice              :  0x100 Device 1.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 LASER Driver 
 iProduct               :    0x2 LASER Driver IJS
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 0001A0000000
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x22 (34 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Human Interface Device ====================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x3 Human Interface Device
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x4 HID
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
```

in Ubuntu 20.04 under Python 3. As can be seen there is no `OUT` endpoint. I am not an expert in USB but as far as I know we need an out endpoint to send data to the device, so this device looks like a read-only device.

However, I know that there is some way of sending/writing data to the device because it is a laser controller and from Windows I can turn on/off the laser, change the intensity, etc. I have part of the C++ source code of this controller for Windows which uses [hidapi](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi). According to [the documentation of `hid_write`](https://codedocs.xyz/GerryFerdinandus/hidapi/group__API.html#gad14ea48e440cf5066df87cc6488493af) it writes to the "Control Endpoint" when there is no other out endpoint, which seems to be the case here. So now I want to replicate this from Python using [PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb).

So far I have this

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import array

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xC251, idProduct=0x2201)

if device is None:
    raise RuntimeError('Device not found')
interface = device[0].interfaces()[0]
endpoint = device[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0] # This is the in endpoint, I can read the status of the laser from here and it works fine.

if device.is_kernel_driver_active(interface.bInterfaceNumber):
    device.detach_kernel_driver(interface.bInterfaceNumber)

cmd = chr(90) # This is the command to turn off the laser.
packet = chr(0) + cmd + chr(0)*(64-len(cmd)-1) # The first byte has to be always 0, see https://codedocs.xyz/GerryFerdinandus/hidapi/group__API.html#gad14ea48e440cf5066df87cc6488493af
packet = array.array('B', [ord(c) for c in packet])
bytes_sent = endpoint.write(packet)
print(bytes_sent) # This prints out 64 so it is fine.
```

which seems to be writing but the laser does nothing (it should turn off). I suspect it is somehow writing into the "IN endpoint" and not into the "Control Endpoint". I would like to **send this `packet` to the control endpoint**. How can this be done?

PD: I have also tried

```
device.write(0x0, packet)
```

but this produces `ValueError: Invalid endpoint address 0x0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write into endpoint 0, you'll need the `device.ctrl_transfer(bmRequestType, bmRequest, wValue, wIndex, packet)` instead of `endpoint.write(packet)`.

The `bmRequestType`, `bmRequest`, `wValue` and `wIndex` correspond to the same elements in the USB control request. The fact that the Windows software uses `hidapi` suggests the control transfers are done according to the USB HID specification.

[This answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52368526/9197000) describes how to make USB HID set/get operations on plain PyUSB.

But since the source code you're porting uses `hidapi`, using the [Python hidapi interface](https://pypi.org/project/hidapi/) might make the process more straightforward. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68101621/9197000) has an example of using `hidapi` in Python, and the answers also talk about alternatives.